# What does respawn="true" mean?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, respawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

a newbie question, I would like to know what does 'respawn="true"' mean in this [tutorial launch file](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode). I did delete it, but nothing changed.
Thanks before.

fins

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37446/what-does-respawn=%22true%22-mean?/) by [fins](https://answers.ros.org/users/2151/fins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-06-28

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In cases where the node shuts down the node will restart automatically.

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-28**:
http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node contains the official documentation.